# Why are polycrystalline solar cells shinier than monocrystalline solar cells?

Tags: energy, semiconductor-physics, material-science, electronics, solar-cells

Being shiny reduces the efficiency of the solar cells. Additional to the grain boundaries that polycrystalline solar cells have that gives resistance to the current flowing in them, they are shinier than monocrystalline cells which reduces their efficiency more than monocrystalline ones.

What is the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Get the right angle on the monocrystalline one and it will be plenty shiny.

Comment: @JonCuster Do you think that this explanation is correct: "Probably simply because the grain boundaries provide more opportunities for light scattering within the medium. A perfectly homogeneous solid may have reflection at the outer boundary as the light enters, but after the light is inside it won't scatter until it hits another boundary. It's sort of like the difference between perfectly clear ice and white ice that's full of bubbles/imperfections. Same material, different structure."

Comment: @JonCuster  I think it should be correct because the light makes the grain boundaries in the solar cell very visible to the eye, bounces off of them.

Comment: Given that visible light in silicon is rapidly adsorbed in a few microns, that explanation seems quite unlikely.